# How to improve time complexity of algorithm to find the longest consecutive subsequence of integers in an array

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

There are multiple approaches to solve the codeforces problem [F. Consecutive Subsequence](https://codeforces.com/contest/977/problem/F):

> You are given an integer array of length
>
> You have to choose some subsequence of this array of maximum length such that this subsequence forms a increasing sequence of consecutive integers. In other words the required sequence should be equal to [,+1,…,+−1] for some value  and length .
>
> Subsequence of an array can be obtained by erasing some (possibly zero) elements from the array. You can erase any elements, not necessarily going successively. The remaining elements preserve their order. For example, for the array [5,3,1,2,4] the following arrays are subsequences: [3], [5,3,1,2,4], [5,1,4], but the array [1,3] is not.

The Python code for one approach I tried that does not use dynamic programming is shown below. To avoid repetition, the if statement checks that the number one lower than the current number is not present in the array before because then it could be included to increase the subsequence's length.

```
A = [3, 3, 4, 7, 5, 6, 8]

def longestConsecutive(nums):
    longest_streak = 0 #length of longest consecutive subsequence of integers
    indices = []
    
    for i in range(1,len(nums)):
        b = set(nums[0:i]) 
        if nums[i-1] - 1 not in b:
            indices.append(i) 
            current_num = nums[i-1]
            current_streak = 1
            k = i

            for j in range(k, len(nums)):  
                if A[j] == current_num + 1:
                    indices.append(j+1) 
                    current_num += 1
                    current_streak += 1
                    k=j   

            if current_streak < longest_streak:
                indices = indices[0:len(indices)-current_streak]  #remove the current_streak's indices 
            else: 
                longest_streak = current_streak  
    
    return [longest_streak,indices[len(indices)-longest_streak:len(indices)]] 

c = longestConsecutive(A) 
print(c[0]) 
print(*c[1])
```

I think the time complexity for this algorithm is O(n) because the second for loop runs at most n times while the first for loop runs n-1 times and each lookup is O(1) because a set b is used. This is explained [on LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-consecutive-sequence/solution/) in the solution to a different but related problem as my code is a modification of the third algorithm discussed. All other computations require constant time. Despite this, the algorithm passes tests 1-4 but fails test 5, for which the size of the input array is 200000 and the 2 second time limit is exceeded. Is the problem that the complexity is actually greater? Does anyone see how the code can be optimized?

Comment: If you have two nested loops each of which is O(n), the combined complexity is O(n²)

Comment: Also `set(nums[0:i])` is O(n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm has a O(²) time complexity.

Already the creation of the sets takes O(1) + O(2) + ... + O() = O(²) time. Although you could avoid this by adding the new value to an existing set (instead of rebuilding it from scratch), the inner loop will still make the time complexity quadratic, and this cannot be resolved by a simple adjustment of the algorithm. Also the slicing that happens in `indices[0:len(indices)-current_streak]` hurts the time complexity.

I don't see a way to tune this algorithm to improve its time complexity, and I think a completely different approach is needed.

#### Another approach

One possible solution that has a O() time complexity -- if we assume that the **amortised** time complexity for a dictionary manipulation is O(1) -- is one where you keep track of where a sequence ends in a dictionary, and store for such end point the size of the sequence that ends there.

So for instance, if we have so far identified a sequence that starts at 5 and ends at 8, it would be represented in that dictionary with `{ 8: 3 }`.

Then, as a next value is read from the input list, and when it is not already a key in that dictionary, we could check if it extends a sequence at the high side. It is then trivial to update the dictionary to represent the new situation.

When all values have been processed like that, it remains to identify the longest sequence using that dictionary.

A Python implementation for this idea can be found in this spoiler:

> `def longestConsecutive(nums):
>      if not nums:  # Boundary case: empty list
>          return 0, []
>      size_for_end = {}
>      for value in nums:
>          if value not in size_for_end:
>              if value - 1 in size_for_end:
>                  # This value extends a sequence
>                  size_for_end[value] = size_for_end.pop(value - 1) + 1
>              else:
>                  # This is a new sequence with just one value
>                  size_for_end[value] = 1
>      # All sequences have been identified, so get the longest
>      size, end = max((size, end) for end, size in size_for_end.items())
>      return size, list(range(end - size + 1, end + 1))`

NB: The related LeetCode problem can be solved by using two dictionaries instead of one, where the second dictionary references the same sequences, but from the viewpoint of the *starting* value of that sequence, so that every sequence is represented by an entry in both dictionaries.

Comment: I am really impressed how short is this code, compared to mine!! Did you submit it to Codeforces?

Comment: No, I don't have an account there.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like a recursive function is easier to understand and follow. Basically you want to only check if your current step is better than before, if not, move forward one. I am sure the sorted part could be made faster as well, as it is clearly not necessary to sort completely to conclude we have a non-inceasing sequence. I leave that to you to improve:

```
def f(x,n=1):
    if len(x)<n:
        return
    elif x[:n]==sorted(x[:n]):
        a = f(x,n+1) 
        return x[:n] if a is None else a
    return f(x[1:],n)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, the issue is to find an efficient algorithm.

What is proposed is create an array of indices (`0 2 3 ... n-1`), and to sort them according to the values of `A[index]`.

The sort must be stable, to manage correctly the duplicates. For example, only the first duplicate is worth to be kept.

When iterating over the sorted indices, if at one time we find an element with a lower index but a higher value, this element must be ignored in a first step. However, its value must be memorized, so that to come back later on on it.

The complexity is dominated by the sort, i.e. `O(nlogn)`.

Here is a C++ code to illustrate the algorithm.
The indices at the output are zero-indexed (C++-style). Just add +1 to get 1-indexed indices.

*Output:*

```
1 3 5 2 4 6         -> 2  [0 3]         -> values: 1 2 
10 9 8 7            -> 1  [3]           -> values: 7 
6 7 8 3 4 5 9 10 11 -> 6  [0 1 2 6 7 8] -> values: 6 7 8 9 10 11 
5 2 3 6 7 4 8 0 9   -> 5  [0 3 4 6 8]   -> values: 5 6 7 8 9
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

void print (const std::vector<int> &A, const std::string &after = "\n", const std::string &before = "") {
    std::cout << before;
    int n = A.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        std::cout << A[i];
        if (i != n-1) std::cout << " ";
    }
    std::cout << after;
}

std::vector<int> long_subseq (std::vector<int>& A) {
    std::vector<int> seq, seq_opt;
    int n = A.size();
    if (n == 0) return seq_opt;
    if (n == 1) {
        return std::vector<int> (1, 0);
    }
    std::vector<int> indices(n);
    std::iota (indices.begin(), indices.end(), 0);
    auto fsort = [&] (int i, int j) {return A[i] < A[j];};
    std::stable_sort (indices.begin(), indices.end(), fsort);
        
    seq.push_back (indices[0]);
    seq_opt.push_back (indices[0]);
    int max_length = 1;
    int length = 1;
    int last_index = indices[0];
    int next_index = -1;
    
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        //std::cout << "i = " << i << "\n";
        if (A[indices[i]] == A[last_index]) continue;     
        if ((last_index < indices[i]) && (A[indices[i]] == A[last_index] + 1)) {
            length++;
            seq.push_back (indices[i]);
            last_index = indices[i];
        } else {
            if (indices[i] < last_index) {
                if (next_index == -1) next_index = i;
            }
            if (A[indices[i]] > A[last_index] + 1) {             
                if (length > max_length) {
                    max_length = length;
                    std::swap (seq_opt, seq);
                }
                length = 1;
                seq.resize(0);
                if (next_index != -1) {
                    last_index = indices[next_index];
                    i = next_index - 1;
                    next_index =  -1;
                } else {
                    last_index = indices[i];
                }
                seq.push_back (last_index);
            } 
        }
    }
    if (length > max_length) {
        max_length = length;
        std::swap (seq_opt, seq);
    }
    return seq_opt;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> examples = {
        {1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6},
        {10, 9, 8, 7},
        {6, 7, 8, 3, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11},
        {5, 2, 3, 6, 7, 4, 8, 0, 9}
    };
    
    for (auto &A: examples) {
        
        auto ans = long_subseq (A);
        print (A, " -> ");
        std::cout << ans.size() << "  ";
        print (ans, "] -> values: ", "[");
        for (int i = 0; i < ans.size(); ++i) {
            std::cout << A[ans[i]] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: With last improvement (there was an efficiency issue for some corner cases), the last code can pass all the tests. Time: 124 ms.